# Custom week calculation where week starts from thursday 7PM in pandas;

Tags: python, pandas, date

I am trying to write a function for calculating ordinal work week starting from Thursday 7 PM. How should I approach this problem using pandas ?

Comment: could you tell us more about your problem? do you have any code? exemple data? exemple output?

Comment: Just to understand, you want to treat Thurs 7pm as Sunday midnight?

Comment: Yes, I want to treat Thursday 7PM as Sunday midnight

Answer (score 0):

Try using an Epoch based date, and then the delta between to calculate

Answer (score 0):

Pandas allows building custom business days and business hours. You should refer to their documentation:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html

Look in the DataOffset Objects section in Custom Business Days and Business Hours subsections for excellent examples.